# Django: How to access array index in template using variable

Tags: arrays, django, indexing, tuples

I have array, lets say it:

```
str_types = ("open", "closed", "extend", "cancel")
```

Also I've some table. Which have int field named "type", contains number from 1 - 4. If field value is 1, It must print "open", if value equals 2, I must print "closed" etc.

So in template:

```
{% for a in ticket %}
<div>{{ str_types.a.types }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Result is blank. How to access that str_types array's index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it without [custom template tag or filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/).

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_by_index(l, i):
    return l[i]
```

And the in the template:

```
{% load my_tags %}
{{ str_types|get_by_index:a.types }}
```

But why you need this?  The django way is to set the [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#choices) attribute of the `types` field and the use it in the template as `{{ a.get_types_display }}`.

Comment: I don't have model. I just reading from existed database, using raw sql.

Comment: Then you have to add the field in the view (simple) or use the template filter (more complicated).  I added the example of such filter to the answer.

Comment: Never created custom filter before. I'll try and report back.

Comment: I just created **templatetags** folder in my app. Then created **__init__.py** empty file. Then created **custom_filters.py**. And put your codes inside it. Then loaded it in template **{% load custom_filters %}**. Then when I try use filter, error happening.

`'custom_filters' is not a valid tag library: Template library custom_filters not found`

Comment: Just restarted my service. And it works :) Thank you much sir.

Comment: From a "modern" JS framework perspective like react/vue etc. this seems awkward.